# Priorities of constructors c++

Tags: c++, constructor, iterator

I got very weird problem

for code like this

```
    template <typename T>
    struct A{
        explicit A(unsigned int size = 0, const T &t = T())
        {
        }
        template <typename InputIterator>
        A(InputIterator first, InputIterator last) {
            for(;first != last ; ++first)
            {
                *first; //do something with iterator
            }
        }
    };
```

when I for example define

```
        A<int> a(10,10);
```

the second constructor for iterators is used instead of first one.
How then vectors constructors work, when they looks preety the same?

```
    explicit vector (size_type n, const value_type& val = value_type(),
             const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());

    template <class InputIterator>
     vector (InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
             const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

And I can make vector v(10,10) without having any troubles.

PS I got error like this

```
      temp.cpp: In instantiation of ‘A<T>::A(InputIterator, InputIterator) [with = int; T = int]’:
    temp.cpp:17:15:   required from here
    temp.cpp:12:4: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason the compiler chooses the second constructor in case of your `A` is simple: your `10` is a value of *signed* type `int`, while `size_type` is some *unsigned* integer type. This means that `10` has to be *converted* to that unsigned integer type. The need for that conversion is what makes the first constructor to lose the overload resolution to the second constructor (which is an exact match for `InputIterator = int`). You can work around this problem by doing

```
A<int> a(10u, 10);
```

This eliminates the need for `int -> unsigned` conversion and makes the first constructor win the overload resolution through "non-template is better than template" clause.

Meanwhile, the reason it works differently with `std::vector` is that the language specification gives special treatment to the constructors of standard sequences. It simply *requires* that `std::vector` constructor invocation with two integers of the same type as arguments is somehow "magically" resolved to the first constructor from your quote (i.e. the size-and-initializer constructor). How each specific implementation achieves that is up to the implementation. It can overload the constructor for all integer types. It can use a functionality similar to `enable_if`. It can even hardcode it into the compiler itself. And so on.

This is how it is stated in C++03, for example

> **23.1.1 Sequences**
>
> **9** For every sequence defined in this clause and in clause 21:
>
> — the constructor

```
template <class InputIterator> 
X(InputIterator f, InputIterator l, const Allocator& a = Allocator())
```

> shall have the same effect as:

```
X(static_cast<typename X::size_type>(f),
  static_cast<typename X::value_type>(l), a)
```

> if InputIterator is an integral type

C++11, takes it even further by approaching it from a different angle, although the intent remains the same: it states that if `InputIterator` does not qualify as input iterator, then the template constructor should be excluded from overload resolution.

So, if you want your class template `A` to behave the same way `std::vector` does, you have to deliberately design it that way. You can actually take a peek into the standard library implementation on your platform to see how they do it for `std::vector`.

Anyway, a low-tech brute-force solution would be to add a dedicated overloaded constructor for `int` argument

```
    explicit A(unsigned int size = 0, const T &t = T())
    { ... }

    explicit A(int size = 0, const T &t = T())
    { ... }
```

That might, of course, imply that you'll eventually have to add overloads for all integer types.

A better solution, which I already mentioned above, would be to *disable* the template constructor for integer arguments by using `enable_if` or similar SFINAE-based technique. For example

```
    template <typename InputIterator>
    A(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, 
      typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<InputIterator>::value>::type* = 0)
```

Do you have C++11 features available to you in your compiler?

Comment: Which are these specifications you are referring to? Does the standard really special-case for the argument type `int, int`? Colour me surprised.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, in N3690 it's [sequence.reqmts]/14, _"If the constructor [...] is called with a type `InputIterator` that does not qualify as an input iterator, then the constructor
shall not participate in overload resolution."_ and 15 _"The extent to which an implementation determines that a type cannot be an input iterator is unspecified,
except that as a minimum integral types shall not qualify as input iterators."_

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: It is not `int, int` specifically, but rather `T, T` where `T` is an integral type, at least the way it is stated in C++03.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil: It was originally, since I misread a part of the question. What is there now is immediately and directly relevant.

Comment: I initially had the same thought about using `is_integral`, but realized it's probably better to specifically enable the template only for certain data types. The example I worked up restricts it to iterators to `T`, depending on what exactly the constructor does that may be what is desired (to turn possible run-time errors into compile-time ones) or too restrictive (in which case something else using `iterator_traits` seems appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

When `InputIterator` is`int`, the instantiated

```
A(int first, int last)
```

is a better match than the instantiated

```
explicit A(unsigned int size = 0, const int &t = int())
```

due to the first argument being `unsigned`. `A<int> a((unsigned int)10,10)` should call the constructor you expect. You can also use [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) to prevent a match unless the constructor really is being passed two iterators to `T`:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct A{
    explicit A(unsigned int size = 0, const T &t = T())
    {
        cout << "size constructor for struct A" << endl;
    }

    template <class I>
    using is_T_iterator = typename enable_if<is_same<typename iterator_traits<I>::value_type, T>::value, T>::type;

    template <typename InputIterator>
    A(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,  is_T_iterator<InputIterator> = 0) {
        cout << "iterator constructor for struct A" << endl;
        for(;first != last ; ++first)
        {
            *first; //do something with iterator
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    A<int>(10,10);

    A<int>((int*)0,(int*)0);

    //A<int>((char*)0,(char*)0); //<-- would cause compile time error since (char *) doesn't dereference to int

    return 0;
}
```

If the condition that both arguments are iterators to `T` is too strict, there are looser formulations. For instance, you can guarantee that both arguments are iterators. You could go further (but not quite as far as the example above) and ensure that they "point" to a type that is *convertible* to `T` (using `std::is_convertible`).

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, the templated thing is a better match, so it is selected. The standard library implementation fight hard to steer for a sensible behavior with all the templated members.  You may want to look up some implementation code for specializations, if you want to implement a similar collection of your own.

Or you may find a way to dodge the problem.

There was a fine GOTW article with all the cases of function overload selection and some advice to fight it.

Answer (score 0):

Your first argument in `A<int>(10, 10)` doesn't match your explicit constructor because `10` is signed, so it's using the templatized constructor instead. change it to `A<int>(10u, 10)` and you may end up with the results you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing a general library, you may want to make the
extra effort, and use template meta programming to catch all of
the cases.  Or simply provide explicit overloads for all of the
integral types.  For less generic use, it is *usually* sufficient
to follow the rule that anytime you provide an overload for any
integral type, you also provide one for `int` (so you would have
a constructor `A::A( int size, T const& initialValue = T() )`,
in addition to the ones you already provide).

More generally: you should probably just make the `size` an
`int`, and be done with it.  The standard library is caught up
in a lot of historical issues, and must use `size_t` by default,
but in general, unless there is a very strong reason to do
otherwise, the normal integral type in C++ is `int`; in
addition, the unsigned types in C++ have very strange semantics,
and should be avoided anytime there is any chance of arithmetic
operations occuring.

Comment: But if I change size_t into int, then A<unsigned int> will not work correctly for example for A<size_t> a(12u,12u). The same if I would use long long as a template A<long long> a(666LL, 13LL) etc.

Comment: @user2460555 If you change the size to `int`, no one is going to write `a( 12u, 12u )`.  On the other hand, you'll still have the problem with `A<double>( 10, 0 )`.  It's a question as to how far you want to go to support such things, and whether they are a real problem.  For a general library like the standard library, they are, and `std::vector<double>( 10, 1 )` must be supported.  For more restricted use, it may be acceptable to require that the second type be correct, e.g. `A<double>( 10, 1.0 )`.